# Can I flush patch a speaker box on a wall with spackle for wallpaper

Tags: patching-drywall

Our family room came wired for surround sound that we won't use (see pic).  I know I can buy metal plates that screw into the boxes after removing the existing covers.  As there's only speaker wires and no electrical, I'm comfortable doing this.

My question is that since we intend to put wallpaper on this particular section of the wall where those boxes are, I need to spackle over the wall plates I install.  That is, I want to completely hide the speaker boxes such that when wallpaper is applied it will completely cover where the boxes were.  Is there a way to do this to ensure the spackle won't crack and the wallpaper won't wrinkle over time?

[image: Speaker Wall Plates]

Comment: remove the covers ....  apply wallpaper to the wall .... wrap each cover with a piece of wallpaper is such a way that the wallpaper pattern on the cover is exactly the same as the pattern on the wall under the cover ... replace the covers over the boxes

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear.  I want to spackle over the covered boxes such that you cannot see them anymore.  I want to hide them in the wall as we want the wallpaper to completely cover where the boxes were.

Comment: Are you OK with completely removing them?

Comment: @icfantv, your post is clear .... i was only presenting an option  that you may not have thought of

Comment: cut a piece of drywall that fits inside the box opening and is flush with the wall .... install a small wooden block inside the box and secure the drywall piece to the block .... tape and mud

Comment: @PhilippNagel yep, totally ok to remove them completely.

Comment: @jsotola, ah, ok.  my bad.

Comment: @jsotola dumb question:  would I anchor the wooden block to the side or back of the box?

Comment: the back would be easiest .... problem with my idea is that it may be a lot of work to trim the block to the right shape if the box is not level with the rest of the wall .... maybe just put in the block as a filler and fill the rest of the box with mud

Comment: Presumably there is a low voltage box ( or something ) inside the wall that the covers are attached to so they would have to be removed in order to follow jsotola's advise. ( which would create a bigger hole )  Since you are covering it with wallpaper you could just fill the box with expanding foam, cut it flush with the wall, fill in the cells and voids with vinyl Spackle or mud, sand, and paper.

Comment: i would remove the cover, fill with canned foam, sand flush, and wallpaper.

Comment: I LOVE the spray foam idea for its simplicity.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to recess the blank cover plates into your drywall, you could try finding the smallest blank cover you can get. They do make them in smaller and larger sizes, though you may need to shop around a bit.
Once you found one that's smaller than what's on there now, install it on the box, and mark the outline on the wall. Remove the plate, trim the drywall around your markings, and re-install the blank cover. It will now be recessed behind the drywall, unless the box itself is exactly flush or protrudes out.
Now you could use tape and drywall mud to make the area flush and apply whatever covering you would like.

Alternatively, you could also remove the boxes completely, for example, by using a saw to cut through the nails that hold them to the joist and then pulling them through the hole. You would then place a thin, short board through the opening (like a piece of 1x4 ripped to fit easily, or plywood), and use that to fix some cut-out drywall into the hole, and then patch as you normally would.
It would look something like this before you place the patch piece over the wood:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to remove box. Add a piece of wood for a backer. Make it longer than hole . Put a screw in the center to hold onto wood.  Add screws into drywall, add small patch. Tape over with three coats.